# How to prove a basis in this problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, change-of-basis

Let $\mathbb{B} = \{1, \cos t, \cos^2 t, \cos^3 t, \cos^4 t\}$ and $\mathbb{C} =\{1, \cos t, \cos2 t, \cos3 t, \cos4 t\}$ and assume the following identities:

- $\cos 2t = -1+ 2\cos^2t$
- $\cos3t = -3+ 4\cos^3t$
- $\cos4t = 1- 8\cos^2t+ 8\cos^4t$

Let $\mathbb{H} = \mathrm{Span}\{\mathbb{B}\}$.

- Explain why $\mathbb{B}$ is a basis for H
- Prove that C is another basis for H by first calculating the $\mathbb{B}$-coordinates of the elements of C

When working on these, I believe that an answer to the first question would refer to the definition of a basis. Isn't being the span of B mean that H **must** have the basis B? Is there a theorem to reinforce this with, or am I completely wrong?

As for the second question, I'm not really sure how to construct a B-coordinate without vectors or a matrix. I'd love a hint for where to start with this.

Comment: Since $H=\operatorname{span} \mathbb{B}$, the set $\mathbb{B}$ is a system of generators of $H$. Since a basis of a subspace is a *linearly independent* system of generators of that subspace, you need to prove that $\mathbb{B}$ is linearly independent in order to answer the first question.

Comment: Great point @Pacciu  I believe I solved this. Do you have any idea of how to go about calculating the B-coordinates of the elements of C?

Comment: On the other hand, for the second question, keep in mind that functions $1$, $\cos t$, $\cos^2 t$, etc... and $\cos 2t$, $\cos 3t$, etc... are your vectors. The problem asks you to find the coordinate vectors of the functions in $\mathbb{C}$ w.r.t. the basis $\mathbb{B}$. The three trigonometric identities given in the text should be of some use. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the linear map $T: H\rightarrow H$. To find the $B$-coordinates of the elements of $C$, for example, $cos (2t)$, you just need to solve
$$cos(2t)=a\cdot 1+b\cdot cos t+c\cdot cos^2 t+d\cdot cos^3 t +e\cdot cos^4 t$$
It is easy to see that $a=-1, c=2, b=d=e=0.$
The matrix of this linear map is
$$\left [ \begin{matrix}
    1 & 0 &-1&-3&1 \\
    0 & 1&0&0&0 \\
    0& 0&2&0&-8\\
    0&0&0&4&0\\
    0&0&0&0&8
   \end{matrix} \right ]
$$

Since the matrix is invertible, $C$ is also a basis.